# Using Output file as Input file in same program in cpp

Tags: c++, file

I was wondering is it possible to write test case file and use that test cases as input file and produce another output file in the same program in c++.

So far, I have tried this:

```
freopen("input.txt","w",stdout);
for(int i=2;i<=20000;i++)
    cout<<i<< " ";
fclose(stdout);
cout<<"Finished writing test cases"<<endl;
freopen("input.txt","r", stdin);
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
....
/*rest of the code including where I write stuff to output.txt*/
```

I opened my input and output files. Input is okay, but `output.txt` does not show any output.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What are you doing after the last line : `freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);` ?

Comment: @Jarvis
I am taking input and processing through a function which eventually write something. rest of the code:

while(cin >> n)
    {
        cout << n << " = ";//endl;
        f(n);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line :

```
fclose(stdout);
```

Put this line at the end of the program, or after the part when you are sure you won't write to a file instead of `stdout`.

I think the code will work as you expect it to be.